# Backbone.js Model previous method not working?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Strangely I noticed that the model previous method is not working the way I thought.. it keeps returning the same value as the get. I think that something is wrong with my code or backbone.js is not upgrading the this._previousAttributes when change event is fired.

```
model = new Backbone.Model()

model.set({attr1: 123})

alert(model.previous("attr1"))  //alert 123 instead of undefined
alert(model.get("attr1"))

model.set({attr1: 312})

alert(model.previous("attr1"))  //alert 321 instead of 123
alert(model.get("attr1"))
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wLKBk/

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`previous` method](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-previous) is only useful while a `"change"` event is happening:

> **previous** `model.previous(attribute)`
>
> During a `"change"` event, this method can be used to get the previous value of a changed attribute.

The `previous` method is only useful inside a `"change"` event handler; similar things apply to [`hasChanged`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-hasChanged), [`changedAttributes`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-changedAttributes), and [`previousAttributes`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-previousAttributes).

You're trying to use `previous` when you're not inside an event handler so you get nonsense. If you want to know what has changed in a model and you need to know outside of `"change"` event handlers, then you'll have to [track it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10221162/479863).